# How to extract and install the Java 8 202 JRE from the OpenJDK 8

Tags: java

Where is the JRE located for the OpenJDK 8 202 update and what does it look like? Additionally, how do I install the JRE as if I downloaded it directly from the Oracle site?

Comment: Do you mean that the OpenJDK doesn't include a separate `jre/` directory? Because that is correct, it doesn't duplicate the executables the way the old Oracle approach did (i.e., a `java` in the `bin/` and the `jre/bin/` directories). There is a JRE only build at [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/index.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot). Still note that the location of some files is slightly different in the OpenJDK build versus the old Oracle build. Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: @KevinO Thank you. I wasn't aware that the directory for that was separate nor was I aware of the JRE only build at AdoptOpenJDK. What I really need to know is which one is the installer that would install it directly on my machine just as if I downloaded it from Oracle as a stand alone?

Comment: So you're looking for the installer that would be the same as if you went to [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) and downloaded the `jre-8u202-windows-x64.exe`? What is your OS and are you looking for 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: @MC10 Exactly! Windows 10 Enterprise both 32 and 64

Comment: What is the difference between the windows_hotspot and the jre-8u202-windows-x64.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to download just the JRE, the releases are here: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases

The one you are looking for would be `OpenJDK8U-jre_x64_windows_hotspot_8u202b08.msi` for 64-bit or `OpenJDK8U-jre_x86-32_windows_hotspot_8u202b08.msi` for 32-bit. This is assuming you are using Windows. If not, please specify in the question or just download the correct binary for your OS.

Comment: Thank you for that information. That is a more direct grab of the JRE which is what I need.